# Grails: Tomcat deployment without restarting the container

Tags: tomcat, grails

Official guide says:

> Tomcat deployment is trivial and
>   requires copying the WAR file into the
>   TOMCAT_HOME/webapps folder and
>   restarting the container.

But this is really painful :-(

Does there any way to deploy app without restarting Tomcat ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Grails tomcat plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/tomcat) has some Gant scripts for this.

```
grails tomcat deploy
grails tomcat undeploy
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to restart the whole container.

Tomcat supports like the most application servers a feature called "Auto Deployment". The only thing you have to do is copy the war-File into the appropriate folder.

Auto Deploy is turned on with the attribute

```
autoDeploy=true
```

on the host tag in your server.xml configuration file.

Default in Tomcat 6 is:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

See the Tomcat documentation for various deployment ways:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying%20on%20a%20running%20Tomcat%20server

Comment: In my experience you will end up with an out of memory exception if you "auto deploy" too many times

Comment: Mmmh, which tomcat version did you use?